# Put selected content from SQL databse in Python variable

Tags: python, sql, database

How can I put the content from a selected point of a SQL database into a Python variable?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried till now and where are you stuck or what stage you are on. 1. Declare the variable 2. Make a connection to a database 3. Get the output of SQL query 4. Redirect the output to the variable

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague since it doesn't give a clear example of what you've tried or what you're trying to do exactly. But if you want to query and retrieve data using SQL from Python, I would suggest to check out [SQLAlchemy](https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to interact with Python from SQL - SQLAlchemy is good and has a ton of features, or [pymssql](https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/) is a bit more lightweight. For either of these, you will need to first set up a connection, and then you'll be able to run whatever query you need to.

Two warnings - first, if you are pulling from a cloud or shared SQL server onto your local machine, be aware of memory constraints for large datasets. Second, if you are working on a shared database, talk to the DBA about whether they would like you to use autocommit if you are running long or slow queries.